# Hide div after page reloaded on sweet alert

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, sweetalert2

i'm using sweetalert in ajax post data, and have a div element that i want to hide after page reload, from the code below what i can do to do that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#approve', function() {
        swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure ?',
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                $('.leftForms').each(function(e) {
                    valuesToSend = $(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax($(this).attr('action'), {
                            url: 'data.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            method: $(this).attr('method'),
                            data: valuesToSend
                        })
                        .done(function(response) {
                            swal.fire({
                                title: 'Data berhasil diupdate!',
                                text: response.message,
                                icon: 'success'
                            }).then(function() {
                                location.reload();
                                localStorage.removeItem('leftcontent');
                                localStorage.getItem('rightcontent', data);
                            });   
                        })
                });
            }
        })
    });
});
```

i want to hide this, at the moment after **location.reload()**, is that possible ?

```
<div id="content1">
<p>blaa..blaa.. bla..</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reloading the page ? You can hide remove the div using JavaScript instead.
Instead of `location.reload();` do `$("#content1").remove();` to remove the element or `$("#content1").hide()` to hide it.
Also `localStorage.removeItem('leftcontent');`  and `localStorage.getItem('rightcontent', data);` isn't being executed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want this choice to actually persist you need to save something to a database for clear reasons, you could use local storage but it will be cleared if the user clears the cache, just save the choice to the local storage then just check for that var when the page reloads and remove the element with:

```js
...
.then(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('choice','hide');
    location.reload();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('choice')=='hide'){
        $("#content1").remove();
    }
...
```

but as @Gazmend pointed out you don't even need to reload the page, just remove the element instead of reloading if reloading is not necessary for other reasons

Comment: why do I reload the page, because when the data has been sent to the database there is a change in status and the data that has been sent cannot be seen again on the current page

Comment: as I said if u need this change to be persistent you need to save this state change somewhere in the backend, you can use local storage to persist the change without saving it to the backend but its only a local (localStorage) change

Comment: note that if the client clears the cache the change is lost, because the solution is using the localStorage, there is no way to persist a change only using client side solutions

Comment: also, if the solution worked mark the answer as solution so other users can find it quicker